# Chakra UI: Correct format of Style Props with React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using Chakra UI. I am creating a react element with React.createElement. I am passing Style Props "align" as second argument to createElement. But when I render this element, contents are not left aligned. What am I missing? What should be the correct format to pass Style Props?

```
const ele = React.createElement(
             VStack,
             {align:"left"},
             comments
            );
```